# How to use several divs with click events to toggle a specific div in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

What im trying to do is following:

I have three different divs with three different ids - #div1,#div2 and #div3.

I have an click event for when i click on those divs.

I have a form.

All those are written in bootstrap

So..  first of all i want to be able to toggle the form itself when clicking on a div AND if i click on #div2 and #div3 the form should show one more div which isnt needed on #div1.

The idea behind this is 
`#div1` should show a form to register something.

`#div2` should show the same form but with a `<select></select>` since its supposed to edit existing entries .

`#div3` basically the same as `#div2`

When i click on `#div2` or `#div3` this div should be toggled on inside the form and when i click on `#div1` it shouldn be toggled off since i dont need that selection there.

**form code which should be toggled depending on the div**

```
      <div class="form-row class1">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label>Select Student ID</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option selected>Choose Student you want to edit</option>
                    <option>Student 1</option>
                    <option>Student 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

First i tried with having 2 different forms `#form1` and `#form2`

and did smth like this for the other form too

```
 // $("#div1").click(function () {
             console.log("hello");
             let f1 = document.getElementById("form1");
             if (f1.style.display === "none") {
                 f1.style.display = "block";
             } else {
                 f1.style.display = "none";
          }

             })
```

but that would lead to duplicated code and just looks overall bad

so i think something like this

```
    $("#div1").click(function () {
                $("form").toggleClass("div class1")
            });
        });
```

would look better and be closer to what i want to have but as you can see im having some issues with how exactly the syntax should be.

Grateful for every anwser! :D

p.s im open to different ideas but as a beginner to front end those were the first ideas that came to my mind.

Cheers, Askir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are usually a couple of ways to tackle things like such.
I think the shortest way to what you are looking for is to simply replace the html inside the form using jQuery (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp). This is not the nicest way to do it, but it does the trick without too much duplication.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#div1").click(() => {
    $(".class1 > div").html(
        `<label>Select Student ID</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option selected>Choose Student you want to edit</option>
            <option>Student 1</option>
            <option>Student 2</option>
        </select>`);
  });
  $("#div2").click(() => {
    $(".class1 > div").html(
      `<label>Select Student ID</label>
       <input />`);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="div1">Form 1</button>
<button id="div2">Form 2</button>

<div class="form-row class1">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label>Empty</label>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Another way is, as you suggested, to `$("#form").show()` on the relevant form, and call `$("#form").hide()` on the others.

Now if you'd want to make conditional renders a better way, I would suggest you venture in to https://reactjs.org.

Comment: Ty very much Thomas for the help! 
I changed the code a bit u gave me to:
```
        <div class="form-row class1">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```
``` 
$("#div3").click(() => {
                $(".class1 > div").html(

                    `<label>Select Student ID</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option selected>Choose Student you want to edit</option>
            <option>Student 1</option>
            <option>Student 2</option>
        </select>`
        );
    });
```

Comment: aand this. 
 $("#div1").click(() => {
                $(".class1 > div").html(
                    ``);
            });

and this inside the form

 <div class="form-row class1">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```
idk if its good or bad but it does the trick as u said :D